# How to provide different dimensions for Samsung S3 and Moto X

Tags: android, screen-resolution

Samsung S3 - 720x1280, xhdpi, 306ppi

Motorola Moto X - 720x1280, xhdpi, 312 ppi

I need to provide different `dimen` for these devices.

I have read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but still didn't found a solution

Looks like problem because `Motorola Moto X` haven't hardware buttons (back, menu, home)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `smallestWidth` ? I think it should do the trick

Comment: @pamobo0609 do you mean `sw312` or `sw306` ?

Comment: "I need to provide different dimen for these devices" -- then you have a serious UI problem. There are over *8,000* Android device models. Creating tailored dimensions for each one will be a very expensive proposition, in terms of time and hardware acquisition costs.

Comment: @CAMOBAP yes! Using this, you can customize the UI for those specific densities, both 306 and 312

Comment: @pamobo0609 no, usually devices are not defined with their physical ppi. They use the bracket, in this case both are xhdpi so both are at 320 ppi. And actually smallestWidth use the 720px (720 is smaller than 1280) so both are at sw360dp.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the UI design if such a minor difference in device specs makes it necessary to use different metrics. What if there is a third similar device in the future? The app should work on it without manual tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google library `PercentRelativeLayout` with this library you can set `width`, `height` and `margin`  of your views by percentage which is great because in all screen they look the same and of course it is not hard to code it. Here example:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

you must add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
}
```

and official documentation by Google https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html
Hope this help for your case!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I didn't know before about this library. Actually I already solved my problem by another way (just changed RelativeLayout to LinearLayout), anyway +1 to you